# Cycloaddition of Silyl Dienol Ethers with Sodium Bromodifluoroacetate: What's the scope?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organometallic-compounds, organosilicon-compounds

I have recently came across this article "Copper(I)-Catalyzed [4 + 1] Cycloaddition of Silyl Dienol Ethers with Sodium Bromodifluoroacetate: Access to
β,β‐Difluorocyclopentanone Derivatives". ([*Org. Lett.* **2016,** *18* (18), 4502–4505](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.orglett.6b02085))

Can anyone explain what is the use of these β,β‐Difluorocyclopentanone Derivatives or where can I find more information about this cycloaddition procedure.
Thanks in advance!